# Cassandra paging on a primary key list does not work

Tags: python, database, cassandra, cassandra-driver, cassandra-4.0

I have a problem with the pagination in cassandra with python connector. I would like to paginate on a list of primary keys.

Here is the schema of the table:

```
client_data.store (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    "additionalCols" text,
    format text,
    name text
)
```

Here is what I have in database:

[database content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXzxd.png)

I would like to have pages of 5 rows by filtering on id from 1 to 15.

I make a first query :

```
stores = (
            Store.Cql.objects.all()
            .filter(id__in=[str(x) for x in range(1, 15)])
            .limit(5)
        )
```

and I get the columns with id :

```
['1', '10', '11', '12', '13']
```

I take the last element, in this case '13' then I do

```
last_element_pk = '13'
token = Token(last_element_pk)
stores = (
            Store.Cql.objects.all()
            .filter(id__in=[str(x) for x in range(1, 15)], pk__token__gt=(token))
            .limit(5)
        )
```

and I get :

```
['1', '10', '11', '12', '14']
```

I don't understand why I have common ids?!

I use cassandra:4.0.1, and cassandra-driver = "^3.25.0"

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Simple reason is that token is hash function which calculates a hash value from the partition key. So saying give me key with formula `gt>13` and saying  give me tokens with formula `gt>token(13)` is different thing. You cannot order partition keys as they are never stored in serial order. So what you are getting is correct as per the query issued. You are asking  `give keys whose  token value is greater than token value of 13`  and `give 5 such keys`. So the response is correct.

Partition keys cannot be ordered by normal partition keys of type(int,long etc)